# How to ensure that database cleanup is always performed after a test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Consider the following example of a unit test. The comments pretty much explain my problem.

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{

  //generate some objects in the database
  ...

  //make an assert that fails sometimes (for example purposes, this fails always)
  Assert.IsTrue(false);

  //TODO: how do we clean up the data generated in the database now that the test has ended here?

}
```

Comment: You should  also use the `TearDown` (or its equivalent in your suite) to clean up because if your test fails, the clean up code won't get executed.

Comment: How about catching an exception, then re-throwing it after cleaning up?

Comment: Jimmy Bogard (author of *AutoMapper*) has a great article and tool: [Reliable database tests with Respawn](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/02/19/reliable-database-tests-with-respawn/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. [One](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182517%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is using TestInitialize and TestCleanup attributes on methods in the test class. They will always be run before and after the test, respectively.

Another way is to use the fact that test failures are propagated to the test runner via exceptions. This means that a try { } finally { } block in your test can be used clean up anything after an assert fails.

```
[TestMethod]
public void FooTest()
{
  try
  {
     // setup some database objects
     Foo foo = new Foo();
     Bar bar = new Bar(foo);
     Assert.Fail();
  }
  finally
  {
     // remove database objects.
  }
}
```

The try/finally cleanup can get really messy is there are a lot of objects to cleanup. What my team has leaned towards is a helper class which implements IDisposable. It tracks what objects have been created and pushes them onto a stack. When Dispose is called the items are popped off the stack and removed from the database.

```
[TestMethod]
public void FooTest()
{
  using (FooBarDatabaseContext context = new FooBarDatabaseContext())
  {
    // setup some db objects.
    Foo foo = context.NewFoo();
    Bar bar = context.NewBar(foo);
    Assert.Fail();
  } // calls dispose. deletes bar, then foo.
}
```

This has the added benefit of wrapping the constructors in method calls. If constructor signatures change we can easily modify the test code.

Comment: I love to nitpick; TestCleanup doesn't run if TestInitialize threw an exception.

Comment: @carlin.scott Your nitpicking just saved my day

Comment: Neither does TestCleanup run if there is an exception in the test itself.  Seems wrong that it doesn't - I should expect cleanup stuff to run in all cases.

Comment: @dudeNumber4 It is not true using Visual Studio 2017 that TestCleanup method is not executed if the test throws an exception. Unless you are debugging the test and you stop the test execution when the exception occurs.

Comment: @LucaCremonesi Sorry.  To clarify: if there is an error in initialize, cleanup won't be called as I would expect. Thus, I have to (remember to) do a bunch of try / catch / manually call cleanup.

Comment: I know it's ten years later but do you have an example of what that helper class looks like to propogate errors?

Answer (score 9):

I think the best answer in situations like this is to think very carefully about what you are trying to test. Ideally a unit test should be trying to test a single fact about a single method or function. When you start combining many things together it crosses over into the world of integration tests (which are equally valuable, but different).

For unit testing purposes, to enable you to test only the thing you want to test, you will need to **design for testability**. This typically involves additional use of interfaces (I'm assuming .NET from the code you showed) and some form of dependency injection (but doesn't require an IoC/DI container unless you want one). It also benefits from, and encourages you to create very cohesive (single purpose) and decoupled (soft dependencies) classes in your system.

So when you are testing business logic that depends on data from a database, you would typically use something like the [Repository Pattern](http://blog.lowendahl.net/?p=249) and inject a [fake/stub/mock](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Double.html) IXXXRepository in for unit testing. When you are testing the concrete repository, you either need to do the kind of database cleanup you are asking about or you need to shim/stub the underlying database call. That is really up to you.

When you do need to create/populate/cleanup the database, you might consider taking advantage of the various setup and teardown methods available in most testing frameworks. But be careful, because some of them are run before and after each test, which can seriously impact the performance of your unit tests. Tests that run too slowly will not be run very often, and that is bad.

In MS-Test, the attributes you would use to declare setup/teardown are [ClassInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx), [ClassCleanUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classcleanupattribute.aspx), [TestInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx), [TestCleanUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcleanupattribute.aspx). Other frameworks have similarly named constructs.

There are a number of frameworks that can help you with the mocking/stubbing: [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks), [NMock](http://nmock.org/index.html), [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/), [Moles and Stubs](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) (VS2010), [VS11 Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (VS11 Beta), etc. If you are looking for dependency injection frameworks, look at things like [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/), [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/), [Castle Windsor](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx), etc.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of responses:

1. If it's using an actual database, I'd argue that it's not a "unit test" in the strictest sense of the term.  It's an integration test.  A unit test should have no such side-effects.  Consider using a mocking library to simulate the actual database.  [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks) is one, but there are plenty of others.
2. If, however, the whole *point* of this test is to actually interact with a database, then you'll want to interact with a transient test-only database.  In that case part of your automated testing would include code to build the test database from scratch, then run the tests, then destroy the test database.  Again, the idea is to have no external side-effects.  There are probably multiple ways to go about this, and I'm not familiar enough with unit testing frameworks to really give a concrete suggestion.  But if you're using the testing that's built in to Visual Studio then perhaps a [Visual Studio Database Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678491.aspx) would be of use.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit too general. Usually you should clean up after every single test. Usually you cannot rely that all tests are always executed in the same order and you have to be sure about what is in your database. For general setup or cleanup most unit test frameworks provide setUp and tearDown methods that you can override and will automatically be called. I don't know how that works in C# but e. g. in JUnit (Java) you have these methods.

I agree with David. Your tests usually should have no side effects. You should set up a new database for every single test.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do manual cleanup in this circumstance. Ie, the opposite of the generate some objects in the db.

The alternative, is to use Mocking tools such as Rhino Mocks so that the database is just a in memory database

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are *actually* testing. Looking on the comments I would say *yes*, but by the way it's difficult to deduct  looking on comments. Cleaning up the object you just inserted you, in practice, reset the state of the test. So if you cleanup, you begin to test from cleanup system.

Answer (score 0):

I think the clean up depends on how you're building the data, so if "old test data" doesn't interact with future tests runs, I think it's fine to leave it behind.

An approach I've been taking when writing integration tests is to have the tests run against a different db than the application db. I tend to rebuild the test db as a precondition to each test run. That way you don't need a granular clean-up scheme for each test as each test run gets a clean slate between runs.
Most of my development i done using SQL server, but I have in some cases run my tests against a SQL Compact edition db, which is fast and efficient to rebuild between runs.

Answer (score 0):

mbUnit has a very handy attribute Rollback that cleans up the database after finishing the test. However, you'll have to configure DTC (Distributed Transaction Coordinator) in order to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a comparable issue where one test's assertion was preventing cleanup and causing other tests to fail.

Hopefully this is of use to somebody, sometime.

```
    [Test]
    public void Collates_Blah_As_Blah()
    {
        Assert.False(SINGLETON.Collection.Any());

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            Assert.That(PROCESS(ValidRequest) == Status.Success);

        try
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, SINGLETON.Collection.Count);
        }
        finally
        {
            SINGLETON.Collection.Clear();
        }
    }
```

The finally block will execute whether the assertion passes or fails, it also doesn't introduce the risk of false passes - which catch will cause!

Answer (score 0):

The following is a skeleton of a test method that I use. this allows me to use a try catch finally to do the cleanup code in the finally block without loosing my assert that fail.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Exception defaultException = new Exception("No real execption.");
        try
        {
            #region Setup
            #endregion

            #region Tests
            #endregion

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        { 
            /*if an Assert fails this catches its Exception so that it can be thrown 
            in the finally block*/
            defaultException = exc; 
        }
        finally
        {
            #region Cleanup
            //cleanup code goes here 

            if (!defaultException.Message.Equals("No real execption."))
            {
                throw defaultException;
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
```