# Mstest [ClassCleanup] not executed at all in VS 2019

Tags: unit-testing, automation, mstest, visual-studio-2019

```
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void BeforeCls(TestContext tc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassInitialize - Before Class");
    }

    [ClassCleanup]        
    public static void AfterCls()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassCleanup - After Class");
    }


    [TestInitialize]
    public void BeforeMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestInitialize - Before Method");
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void AfterMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestCleanup - After Method");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test Method - 1");
    }
```

Class cleanup is never executed in this code. 
here is the Output
ClassInitialize - Before Class
TestInitialize - Before Method
Test Method - 1
TestCleanup - After Method

Answer (score 3):

Invested a bit more time and discovered that using this will work within a test class:

```cs
[ClassCleanup(InheritanceBehavior.None))]
public static void ClassCleanup()
{
    // Your code goes here
}
```

And using that will work for a derived test class:

```cs
[ClassCleanup(InheritanceBehavior.BeforeEachDerivedClass)]
public static void ClassCleanup()
{
    // Your code goes here
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/143).

---

If the solution is not working for you no matter what, you can define `IDisposable`. The code will look something like this:

```cs
[TestClass]
public class DisposableBaseTest : IDisposable
{
    // Your initialize methods

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~DisposableUserBaseTest()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // Your cleanup code
            Console.WriteLine("ClassCleanup - After Class");
        }
    }
}
```

---

P.S. And according to [carlin.scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576153/carlin-scott) from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860562/how-to-ensure-that-database-cleanup-is-always-performed-after-a-test), if you receive an exception during `ClassInitialize`, you want to handle this separately.

Comment: [ClassCleanup(InheritanceBehavior.None,ClassCleanupBehavior.EndOfClass)] worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ClassCleanup` is executed - put a breakpoint inside your method and verify it yourself. Problem is, that this method is executed **after** all of your tests are completed, so you cannot write message from that method in test output report. This is similar to `ClassInitialize` method. If you have multiple tests in your file, your `ClassInitialize` will write a message to only one of them.

Comment: Hi Peska, Thank you for your reply. My project has just code for mstest with test class & test method. I have 1 test class and 1 test method. i tried breakpoint in my mstest project but this breakpoint is not hit (debug or release). When i run my mstest project, in output window i am able to print ClassInitialize - Before Class, TestInitialize - Before Method, Test Method - 1, TestCleanup - After Method but NOT ClassCleanup. Can you please help me on this.